# Alfresco : Pull E-Mails without imap

Tags: alfresco

In alfresco I need to pull email from my organization mail id(Mail client:Outlook). But in my organization, there is no imap server enabled. So I need some other alternative to pull email from my organization mail id to alfresco repository.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you make use of [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/). That provides a bridge between Exchange OWA and IMAP. You configure up a copy of DavMail with your Exchange credentials, then point Alfresco at DavMail so it can fetch the email.

Well, either that, or enable the inbound SMTP functionality in Alfresco, and arrange for all the emails to be forwarded / bounced to an address on Alfresco. That'd be push rather than pull though, not sure if that'll work for your case or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to do it manually (drag-and-drop), I have found so far that dragging to CIFS folders is much faster and scalable. The only problem is that Alfresco does not offer automatic support for *.msg files, so you would have to create a rule and script to extract the text and attachments. Fortunately, Alfresco already uses POI (there are 3 POI jar files), and you can use those libraries to extract the files. Just keep in mind that such script would have to live in the Alfresco classpath, or it will be unable to make use of the POI libraries. Also, you may have to move the POI*.jar files to the tomecat/lib directory, so those jars can be used by your script. Take a look to the Mozilla Rhino reference for more details about the script.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Alfresco's inbound email.

Link Alfresco as an account to your outlook: [SMTP Inbound server](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Inbound_SMTP_Email_Server_Configuration)

Then follow this guide to create a Marco in outlook: [Forward Macro](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f57/outlook-rule-with-send-from-account-option-566130.html)

Then create a rule to fire the script with some conditions you'd like and you're automatically forwarding your incoming mails to Alfresco.